# Divide circle and subcircle evenly by area

Tags: geometry, circles, area

How do you divide a circle into a certain number of shapes with the same area while having at least one sub circle dividing the whole figure?
I know that if we divide along the center of the circle in even angles the shapes cut are the same in size so therefore their area would be the same.

[image: Circles divided by center]

What I want is something along the lines of this:

[image: Circles with subcircles divided]

where a subcircle of any radious is present inside but the pieces of it still have the same area as the pieces outside.

Comment: By subcircle, do you mean cocentric circle?

Comment: Going off your first example, having the subcircle be 2/3 the area of the whole circle would satisfy your conditions, no?